# django startproject problem in python everywhere

Tags: python, django, django-models

[image]

I have been struggling with this problem in python everywhere. how could I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to reconsider the project name but the issue is that you writing `python`.

Try this:

```bash
django-admin start-project myapp
```